# Django Link to class based views url

Tags: python, django

I created with django a page where I can delete my blog articles using the [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/), I want to add link to each article but I'm struggling to do it.

**here is the code to link to the class based view**

**views.py**

```
user_delete_article = Article.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

**template.html**

```
{% for article in user_delete_article %}
<p><a class="readmore" href="{% url "article.views.DeleteView" article.id %}">{{ article.titre }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$', DeleteView.as_view(), name="DeleteView"),
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Docs are pretty good for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: @Austin I'm sorry, but I couldn't find the topic that concern the class based views. Where is it?

Comment: You're paying too much attention to the fact that it is a class based view. Your url has a name keyword argument of "DeleteView". Focus on that when building your url just like they do in the docs.

Comment: @Austin I did it read the docs, but I keep getting this error `Reverse for 'article.views.DeleteView.as_view()' with arguments '(20,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`, the code I published in my post works fine for normal views class. I'm going to read it again, I'll tell you if I have some news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is django 1.8

```
 <a href="{% url "DeleteView" id=article.id %}">
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Can you explain me why you call directly the DeleteView without using article.views.DeleteView? I thought that I should've give the path to django to call my view

Comment: You don't use the `DeleteView` class or anything, you use the `name` you set in `url()`, which is just a string and nothing more.